# Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashboardComponent'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to solve this issues but I couldn't.
I am new in angular 2. i am creating an app.
But got this error, can anyone suggest me that where i am doing wrong ?
Error is:

**EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashboardComponent'**

My Code is:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  template: ` <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector:'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ]

})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
 heroes: Hero[] = [];
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
 }
```

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { ShubhComponent } from './my.component';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Where are your outlets? How do they look like?

Answer (score 2):

You should define a `<router-outlet>`. Your `AppComponent` template is missing this tag. This tag is necessary to let the router know where to insert your components defined in your routing module:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  template: ` <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- here -->
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```