# Cannot find primary outlet to load 'XYZComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've got ng2 code loading in a .Net MVC component but the following error displays in the console:

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UsersComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'UsersComponent'

Any idea what the issue might be?  I'm using ng2-final and my *app* does work.  However, I've been asked to dev a reference implementation so I need to make sure that errors don't display in the console after the page loads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashboardComponent'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845928/error-cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load-dashboardcomponent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you are using the Router and you haven't declared an outlet for the router to use in your HTML:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: thanks domfx!  that clears the extraneous errors from the console. however, one problem is that, in my implementation, this is updating the url with the route at the end.  ex localhost:8080/users.  I need to load this component dynamically into the site as an independent component without modifying the url path since i'm trying to integrate ng2-final into an mvc app.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can help with that, sorry.

Comment: looks like it can be accomplished via the skipLocationChange option:

this.router.navigateByUrl('path', { skipLocationChange: true });

However, all of my routes are configured for my RouterModule in a Route[] and I don't see a skipLocationChange property available on the Route object.