# Using one component for parent and child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components, angular2-routing

I have created a lazy loaded module which has to load a component when user redirects to route But I am getting an error as stated below:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'XYZComponent'
```

Here is my module.

```
import { XYZComponent } from './xyz-confirm'

const XYZConfirmRoute: Route[] = [
  { 
    path: '', component: XYZComponent ,
    children: [
        { path: 'test', component: XYZComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(XYZConfirmRoute)
  ],
  declarations: [XYZComponent],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]  
})
export class XYZConfirmModule { }
```

As you can see above I want to load `XYZComponent` for both parent and child routes. is there any way to achieve this?.

Comment: same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167047/cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load-xyzcomponent

Comment: but is it the right way to load same component for both parent and child routes?

Comment: the outlet isn't found, you should define outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply do this

```
  {
    path: 'test', component: XYZComponent
  },{
    path: '', component: XYZComponent
  }
```

***NOTE*** You must define narrowed path on the top as I did **test** is on the top and then **''**